# how to use bool, if statements, while statements, used to check the validity of user input

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

I've been trying to create a password checker with the following code below.

```
bool alpha = false;
bool digit = false;
bool nogo = true;
char pass[99];
int len;
len = strlen(pass);
int i, x;

while(nogo){

printf("Password checker 1.1\n");

printf("Please enter a password you would like to test.\n");
scanf("%s\n", pass);
printf("%d\n", len);

    if(len<8){
        printf("Your password is too short. Please re-enter a new password.");
        nogo = true;
    }

    if(len>20){
        printf("Your password is too long. Please re-enter a new password.");
        nogo = true;
    }

    else{
        for (int i = 0, len = strlen(pass); i < len; i++){
            if(isalpha(pass[i]) == true){
                alpha = true;
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0, len = strlen(pass); x < len; i++){
            if(isdigit(pass[x]) == true){
                digit = true;
            }
        }
    }

if(alpha == true && digit ==true ){
    printf("Your password is good.");
    nogo = false;
    return 0;
}
}
```

Everything was built with no errors. However, the code past the first input of the password did not seem to run properly. I had to enter an input twice it prompted for another input of password. Also, it refused to accept the second input from the user. The following is what is shown on my console.

```
Password checker 1.1
Please enter a password you would like to test.
asdasdada
dsadsadadasdaewqkjlks
6
Your password is too short. Please re-enter a new password.
```

"asdasdada
dsadsadadasdaewqkjlks" ---->they are my inputs and the '6' following my inputs are supposed to be my strlen.

May i ask what is the problem with my code? It was my first time using the bool so may i ask if i used the code the right way?

Comment: `len = strlen(pass);` this is **undefined behavior**, your `pass` isn't initialized at that time.

Comment: Also in your second `for` loop, you are incrementing `i` again and probably meant to increment `x`. In both loops you are using inline declaration form so you should remove your `int i, x` declaration at the top of the function (or remove the `int` declaration from both `for` loops).

Comment: Thanks @user3121023! it solved the problem of having to input the password the second time before displaying the`strlen`. It also displayed my `strlen` correctly. I still can't re-enter a new password to test.

Comment: @TypeIA nice! i can now re-enter a password to test and it leaves me with the correct strlen. However, it doesn't seem to run this piece of code though. `if(alpha == true && digit ==true ){
    printf("Your password is good.");
    nogo = false;
    return 0;`

Comment: it jumps straight to the start of the while loop and prompts for a new password to be entered without checking the criteria of `isalpha(pass[i])` and `isdigit(pass[x])`.

Comment: @NewbieCody The return value of [`isalpha()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and [`isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) are not booleans. They are numbers where zero means the character is not of that type and nonzero means it is. So, instead of `== true` the condition should be `!= 0` and these are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `len = strlen(pass);` after `scanf("%s\n", pass);` and not `scanf("%s\n", pass);` it is `scanf("%s", pass);` .
You have made mistake in second for-loop also for `(int x = 0, len = strlen(pass); x < len; i++)` it should be **x++** not **i++**.

Try this code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    bool alpha = false;
    bool digit = false;
    bool nogo = true;
    char pass[99];
    int len;
    int i, x;

    while (nogo)
    {

        printf("Password checker 1.1\n");

        printf("Please enter a password you would like to test.\n");
        scanf("%s", pass);
        len = strlen(pass);
        printf("%d\n", len);

        if (len < 8)
        {
            printf("Your password is too short. Please re-enter a new password.");
            nogo = true;
        }

        if (len > 20)
        {
            printf("Your password is too long. Please re-enter a new password.");
            nogo = true;
        }

        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (isalpha(pass[i])) // not needed if(isalpha(pass[i]) == true) 
                {
                    alpha = true;
                }
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
            {
                if (isdigit(pass[x]))// not needed if(isdigit(pass[x]) == true)
                {
                    digit = true;
                }
            }
            if (alpha == true && digit == true)
            {
                printf("Your password is good.");
                nogo = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; // return 0 position was wrong.
}
```